# Как сделать валидацию на javascript?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, валидация

Есть стандартный скрипт валидации bootstrap

```
  'use strict'

  var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

  Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
    .forEach(function (form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
          event.preventDefault()
          event.stopPropagation()
        } 
        form.classList.add('was-validated')
      }, false)
    })
})()
```

Но он проверяет, только пустые ли значения.
А нужно проверить например, содержит ли поле input с id=year
четыре цифры.

Comment: модифицифируйте функцию `checkValidity` соответствующим образом.

Comment: Подробнее можно, с примером кода?

Comment: пардоньте, это оказывается стандартный метод формы. Но собственно 4 цифры в инпуте вы можете проверить с помощью  `<input id="year" pattern="20\d\d" />` для диапазона 2000-2099 например.

Comment: Это вариант, но Safari не поддерживает (

Answer (score 0):

Стоит попробовать регулярные выражения. Либо замена, как в примере, либо просто проверять совпадения

```js
console.clear();

let inp = document.querySelector('input');
let btn = document.querySelector('button');

const valid = (val) => {
  val = val.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'').slice(0,4);
  inp.value = val;
}

btn.addEventListener('click' , () => {
  valid(inp.value);
})
```

```html
<input type="text" data-validation="4-symbols" value="123456789asd">
<button>GO</button>
```